# Way to have variables, that can be accessed and modified from every Activity class

Tags: android, variables, storage

I want to hold all my variables somewhere where every `Activity` can access them and modify them. I tried storing my variables in `xml` file but it only works one way, I can access them but not modify them. The other option that I have thought about is creating seperate helper class that holds all my variables and offers `getValue();` and `setValue();` methods, but problem with this is that I think it will be resetted every time I make object of this class. So Is there any other way to have storage for variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your senod option is nearer.

In your Helper class just add a **static variable**

See:

```
Class MyHelper {
..
..
public static int globIntVar;
```

Where you want to use :

```
MyHelper.globIntVar = 2;  //  Setter
public int var = MyHelper.globIntVar;  //  Getter
```

Comment: this Option is nearer but maybe cause memory leaks for Appliction

Answer (score 1):

You can use [android.app.Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) for Sharing data between diffrence components of Appliction. see this post:

[Android: How to declare global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Your requirement is to create some Global Variables, you can create some Global Variable by Using Application Class.

Check Example:

[How to declare global variables in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708012/android-how-to-declare-global-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Make one class in your application which store all variables which are used through out application ex.

```
public Class Const{
Public static int siteurl="http://www.xyz.com/";
}
```

Now where ever you want to use that variable write

```
Const.siteurl
```